# How to color two tables in a different way using the same names for th and td?

Tags: html, css, spotfire

I have 2 KPIs that I want to transport to HTML to have 2 values one below the other but with the same size. This is the current [KPIs colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVMcU.png), and I want to keep the same colours differences in the HTML

```
<HEAD>
<STYLE>
table {
  table-layout: fixed ;
  width: 100% ;
}
tr, td {
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25% ;
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<TABLE width="100%" align=center>

<TBODY>

<TR>
<TD align=left background= "2f4e62">
    <br>
    <FONT color=145c98 face="Arial" size=5>
    <SPAN><b>&nbsp;<SpotfireControl id="48ac888b3e154a5bb7dc449c167d036b" /></b></SPAN>
    
    </FONT>
    </br>
    <FONT color=145c98 face="Arial" size=3>&nbsp;MAX VEICOLI PESANTI
    
    <br>
    <FONT color=145c98 face="Arial" size=5>
    <SPAN><b>&nbsp;<SpotfireControl id="7dddd2eeed054fe98e913bc6ecb7d579" /></b></SPAN>
    
    </FONT>
    </br>
    <FONT color=145c98 face="Arial" size=3>&nbsp;MAX VEICOLI LEGGERI</TD>
    
</TR>

</TBODY></TABLE>
```

When I assign a different background colour to TD directly it doesn't work, and if I assign it to tr, td it changes the colours even to the KPI to the left. How can I fix this specific table colour?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you share an screenshot of the wanted result?

Comment: Please don't use table for layout purpose....[font tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated..... I'll suggest to use HTML5

Comment: @Webdeveloper_Jelle the picture in the link is the wanted result. Sorry it's not as clear because this program has some technical jargon, but the HTML I have currently doesn't differentiate two colors, and I want to have 2 different colors for the 2 columns.

Comment: @tech_ofedges you can use nth-child for 2 columns. here is a example. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_nth-child

Comment: This is not tabular data and a table is not an appropriate use here. As you want simply 2 columns you could use Flexbox or grid. Beyond that, where is the difficulty in simply styling the tables differently by using `nth-child` or different id's?

Comment: @tacoshy yeah, problem is my boss is adamant on using this wrong approach. When I use `nth-child`, the problem is always that this action is enabled for all of the page rather than just for the table I have in my spotfire dashboard. Is there a workaround maybe using nth-child specifically for my table? Say I call it myTable

Comment: Is the HTML produced by spotfire and therefore unchangeable?

Comment: _"Say I call it myTable"_ - and "calling" it would mean what exactly? Are you talking about an ID, a class name, ...?